# need to format excel cell based on results of its own formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a simple formula in a cell; specifically =IF(E9="","",(E10/E9)*60).
I have applied rules based on the value of the formula's result, but they do not get applied.  If I copy-paste-special the cell's contents to change from formula to data, the formatting applies.  Is there a way to make Excel automatically "see" the result and format accordingly?

Comment: Please disregard this question; it has started working correctly on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TEXT() function. The second argument of this function is the actual format you want your number (first argument) to be formatted.
You will have to define your format according to the rules you are trying to apply to the results of your formula.

Comment: Thanks Thales but I just logged in to withdraw my question because when I opened the file again to enter more data it worked fine.  Why not, then yes?  I have no idea, but not looking a gift horse............  Thanks again anyway.